# Error starting Jira on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: java, macos, jira, osx-yosemite

I have been running Jira 6.1.5 on a Mac mini with OS X Mavericks and Java 7 for some time. This has been working just fine.
However, recently I updated the OS to Yosemite (10.10.3) and also installed Java 8. But now Jira refuses to start up.
If I execute:

`sudo ./start-jira.sh`

Jira appears to start as normally but then fails with:

`Server startup logs are located in /Users/Michael/JIRA/logs/catalina.out
Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined
At least one of these environment variable is needed to run this program`

I have tried to execute:

`export JAVA_HOME='/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8'`

but this doesn't seem to make any difference.
There are no logs in /Users/Michael/JIRA/logs/ at all.

Any help is appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. I added:

`export JAVA_HOME='/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7'`

to the beginning of ~/JIRA/bin/start-jira.sh

I guess only Java 1.7 was registered. For some reason it couldn't accept -v 1.8.